# Why does EF Seed Method Insert Null on DateTime?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to implement the AddOrUpdate method in my Code-First EF 6 project. I get an error saying that nulls are not allowed in the property AdmCreatedDate. Below the error:

> Running Seed method. System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'AdmCreatedDate', table 'TPPX.dbo.ExemptionCalculationConfig'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

Here is my code...
I have a model called ExemptionCalculationConfig:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TPPX.Domain.ExemptionModels.Entities.Lookups;

namespace TPPX.Domain.ExemptionModels
{
    [Table("ExemptionCalculationConfig")]
    public class ExemptionCalculationConfig : TPPXBaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Priority { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ExemptionApplyLevel")]
        public string ApplyAtLevelCode { get; set; }

        public virtual ExemptionApplyLevel ExemptionApplyLevel { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ExemptionApplyType")]
        public string ApplyByValueOrPercentageCode { get; set; }

        public virtual ExemptionApplyType ExemptionApplyType { get; set; }
        public bool IsProratable { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you can see this class inherits TPPXBaseEntity:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TPPX.Domain
{
    public class TPPXBaseEntity
    {
        [DefaultValue(true)]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public DateTime  AdmCreatedDate { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string AdmCreatedUser { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string AdmCreatedUserFullName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? AdmModifiedDate { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string AdmModifiedUser { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string AdmModifiedUserFullName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Then I have my Configuration.cs file in my Migrations folder:
I have tried adding a list of objects to save in the DB as well as just a single instance. Also, I have explicitly tried creating a DateTime Object called seedCreatedDate, used DateTime.Today and even DateTime.ParseExact() as values for AdmCreatedDate, but no luck :(

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using PA.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager;
using TPPX.Domain.ExemptionModels;
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Linq;

namespace TPPX.DAL.Migrations.TPPXDBContext
{


    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TPPX.DAL.DBContexts.TPPXDBContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            MigrationsDirectory = @"Migrations\TPPXDBContext";
        }

        protected override void Seed(TPPX.DAL.DBContexts.TPPXDBContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.
            //var seedCreatedDate = new DateTime(2018, 07, 26);

            //var exemptionCalculationConfigs = new List<ExemptionCalculationConfig>
            //{
            //    new ExemptionCalculationConfig
            //    {
            //        AdmCreatedDate = DateTime.Today,
            //        AdmCreatedUser = "carcruz",
            //        AdmCreatedUserFullName = "Cruz, Carlos (PA)",
            //        Priority = 1,
            //        IsProratable = false,
            //        ApplyAtLevelCode = "A",
            //        ApplyByValueOrPercentageCode = "P",
            //        IsActive = true
            //    },
            //    new ExemptionCalculationConfig
            //    {
            //        AdmCreatedDate = DateTime.Today,
            //        AdmCreatedUser = "carcruz",
            //        AdmCreatedUserFullName = "Cruz, Carlos (PA)",
            //        Priority = 2,
            //        IsProratable = false,
            //        ApplyAtLevelCode = "V",
            //        ApplyByValueOrPercentageCode = "V",
            //        IsActive = true
            //    }
            //};

            //exemptionCalculationConfigs.ForEach(
            //    x => context.ExemptionCalculationConfigs.AddOrUpdate(e => e.Priority, x));

            context.ExemptionCalculationConfigs.AddOrUpdate(
                e => e.Priority,
                new ExemptionCalculationConfig
                {
                    AdmCreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                    AdmCreatedUser = "carcruz",
                    AdmCreatedUserFullName = "Cruz, Carlos (PA)",
                    Priority = 1,
                    IsProratable = false,
                    ApplyAtLevelCode = "A",
                    ApplyByValueOrPercentageCode = "P",
                    IsActive = true,
                    AdmModifiedDate = null,
                    AdmModifiedUser = null,
                    AdmModifiedUserFullName = null
                });
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I have seen others have this same error when they do not explicitly say their primary key should not be an identity column, but it is not my case. What am I missing?

Comment: Add `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute to the AdmCreatedDate property.  That column in the database should probably be created with a default of GETDATE() or GETUTCDATE(), so the database generates the value, not the application.

Comment: Looks like the `AdmCreatedDate` has been configured as `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` via fluent API, in which case EF won't send the value when doing `INSERT`. But at the same time the database table column does not have set up `DEFAULT`, hence the exception.

Comment: @RobertMcKee IMHO the exception message indicates the opposite of what you are saying.

Comment: @RobertMcKee See the property type in the model - it's `DateTime` (not nullable), so there is no way you can explicitly try to insert null. Only EF can do that, and that's happening when the property is marked as identity or computed.

Comment: I guess @Cai Cruz changed database schema by `DbMigration`. could you please show how did you configure `Up()`? the issue is probably over there.

Comment: @GertArnold No Key on TPPXBaseEntity, those are just shared props all our models at the company share.

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to read and provide feedback I have figure out the problem thanks to @IvanStoev remark on calculated properties. If you put as an answer why I can't have calculated properties using fluent API and use the seed method I will give you the correct answer. Keep in mind, I also did try to not give a value to AdmCreatedDate and the seed method still failed. Some light on why that happens would be great :)

Comment: I hate to just give a link, but this has a fairly decent overview of how to set up your data migrations and how to use fluent API to configure the database to have a default set on the datetime field: http://lancelarsen.com/entity-framework-code-first-computed-getdate/  This link uses "Computed", which is fine for an update datetime field, but create datetime should never change after the initial insert, so "Identity" is a better choice.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Thank you for the info, Robert, I did figure out multiple ways to have a default value in the AdmCreatedDate property, however that still leaves the enigma as to why computed properties conflict with the seed method.

Comment: This can only occur if you operate against a database without the default constraint while EF counts on it. Normally the check on the migration table should prevent such mismatches though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, guys.

I figure it out (kinda).

Thanks to IvanStoev who pointed out computed and identity properties.

I did have the following line in my DbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Where(x => x.Name == "AdmCreatedDate")
.Configure(c => c.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed));
```

For some reason, EF does not like it when the Seed method tries to run and the object has a computed property. I spoke to the project lead and convinced her to take that computed off of EF (since it does not even affect the DB. EF handles it on the code only. After checking the DB in SQL Server I noticed the column is not actually set as computed) Honestly, I don't like this because if in the future we decide to not use EF, the computed properties will be lost.

So, in summary, you can't have models with computed properties in the Seed() method

Now, we handle the computed column in the actual DB.

What would be nice to know, which I was not able to find on the web is why EF behaves this way. If anyone knows, please do let me know.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: *I noticed the column is not actually set as computed* -- well, that's the problem, as I already tried to tell you in my last comment. When you tell EF that a column value is database-generated the value *should* be database-generated. EF counts on it and doesn't provide a value in insert statements. It only ever *reads* the value in LINQ statements.

Comment: @GertArnold Right, but shouldn't EF set the column as computed by me placing the following line using fluent API in the actual SQL Server DB?

`modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Where(x => x.Name == "AdmCreatedDate").Configure(c => c.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed));`

If that's not the case, then what does that line actually do? Because my DB did not have it as computed only EF knew this

Comment: Anyone figure this out? I'm blown away at the fact that I've spent an entire day fighting with default dates and guids. I'm failing to understand why one would use EF6 at this point.